# How to disable implicit import in typescript

Tags: typescript, import, module

First of all, 'implicit import' is not a official term.

Here's what I called 'implicit import' thing.

I have 2 ts files:

file1: app.ts

```
import * as angular from 'angular'; // (*)
import component from './component';
```

file2: component.ts

```
const component : angular.IComponentOptions = {
    templateUrl: 'component.template.html'
};

export default component;
```

Here, in component.ts, even though the `angular` is not imported, typescript compiler never shows any error. If I remove `(*)` line in app.ts file, then typescript compiler complains that there's no angular namespace, so I thought that modules imported in app.ts are also implicitly imported in component.ts when app.ts imports component.ts. That's why I call this behavior 'implicit import'.(Please let me know the official term for this behavior if exists)

How to disable this behavior? I want to make each ts file as complete one as possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> First of all, 'implicit import' is not a official term.

The term you are looking for is `global module`. Whichever type definition of `angular` you are using defined a *global* `angular` and therefore you can use this *global* without importing it.

If a type definition defines a global ... and you use that type definition (which I am assuming you have to) ... you get a global. No two ways around it sorry.

Answer (score 1):

You've run into [this TypeScript issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26233): UMD globals such as `angular` can be used in type positions even from a module.  Ryan Cavanaugh claimed TypeScript was working as intended, but I agree with the reporter of that issue that the behavior makes no sense.